# Linked List from text file (trouble printing)

Tags: java, linked-list

I need to create a Linked List from a text file that looks like this:

```
john, peter, maria, dan, george, sonja
fred, steve
ann, tom, maria
//etc...
```

I want to print the first name in each line (leader) and the remaining names in the line (associated with that name).

So for example:

```
Leader: John Friends: peter, maria, dan, george, sonja Friend Count: 5
Leader: Fred Friends: steve Friend Count: 1
//etc...
```

This is what I have so far:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    LinkedList<String> list = new LinkedList<String>();

    LinkData ld1 = new LinkData();
    JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser(".");
    int returnVal = chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
    if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        System.out.println("You chose to open this file: "
                + chooser.getSelectedFile().getName()
                + "Print some info"

        // open and read file:
        Scanner scanner = null;
        try {
            scanner = new Scanner(chooser.getSelectedFile());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println(e);
            error();
        } 

        if (scanner == null)
            error();


        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {

            String line = scanner.nextLine();
            Scanner lineScan = new Scanner(line);
            lineScan.useDelimiter(", ");
            // System.err.println("The line that was scanned: " + line);

            String leader = lineScan.next();

            while (lineScan.hasNext()) {
                list.add(lineScan.next());
            }
            System.out.println("Leaders include_" + leader + list.toString());
        }  
    }
        }

private static void error() {
    System.err.println("An error has occurred: bad data");
    System.exit(0);
}
}
```

Right now, the first name is printing fine, but then the linked list keeps growing and growing so the results don't print the way I want...

Comment: Shouldn't your second line be `Leader: Fred Friends: steve Friend Count: 1`?

Comment: yep, just changed it. thanks for catching that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should [clear()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/List.html#clear%28%29) the list between 2 line reads

```
while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
  list.clear();
  //...
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed! I cleared it outside of the while-loop though- & it worked perfectly!

Comment: @tommy1370: You are most welcome, and good luck with your homework

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track. You are processing each line into a `leader` and a list of `friends`. You will want to keep track of each of those entities in another object - I would recommend a Map. Something like:

```
Map<String, List<String>> leaderMap = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

// ...
String leader = lineScan.next();

while (lineScan.hasNext()) {
    list.add(lineScan.next());
}

leaderMap.put(leader, list);
```

Don't forget to reinitialize the list for each line you read from the file. At the end you can iterate the map, print the key (`leader`), and size of associated list (`number of friends`). Good luck!